# How to get text to sit nicely in rotated div element

Tags: html

For a site I am making I want to have a nice rotated "navigation" bar, just simple links really at the top of the page.

The code I have got:

```
div.home
{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 700px;
height: 150px;
width: 40px;
background-color: #313131;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
margin-top: -36px;
text-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

And:

```
<div class="home">
Home
</div>
```

This makes the text bunch up at the top of the element. Ideally I want it to be at the bottom of the element,

Comment: No idea if this will have any effect, but have you tried setting the `text-align` CSS property?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change anything however. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't Know what exactly you want but these maybe helpful

```
<div class="home">
  <div class="text">    
    Home
  </div>
</div>​

div.home
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: 700px;
 height: 150px;
 width: 40px;
 background-color: #313131;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 margin-top: -36px;
 -webkit-text-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.text{
  margin-top:100px;
 font-size:26px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 color:white;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/RQVWY/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

Don't transform the text. `transform` (and `-ms-transform`, `-webkit-transform` and so on) include rotating text with it and receive mouse events in the new position.

Comment: I have done this now but am still having the current problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're having trouble with but change the `top` value to something like `'30px'`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6FFQ/)

Comment: I don't think we were ever on the same page. However someone else answered my question (see above). I guess I should have explained it a lot more clearly.

Thanks for the effort though, I do appreciate it. (: